# PDFjs not Installed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf.js

I am trying to use PDF.js to view PDFs in my ASP.Net MVC application via Angularjs.  However, when I use the Nuget package installer, it says that it has successfully intstalled PDF.js 1.3.91, but no files were added to my project, only the packages.config under .nuget folder is there.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? In my experience, the newest ASP.NET5/MVC6 project template don't play well with JS nugget packages. (Ie. the scripts are not copied in the project at all...)

Comment: MVC 5.  I tried to add manually, but I'm not sure what dependencies I need.